# monit doesn't start the script

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, admin, monit

I'm trying to test `monit`. The idea is I have some python script that prints out text, I also have a shell script that acts as a start/stop script. This shell script redirects output to the file called `fetch_output`.

What I want to do is to make `monit` to check for the timestamp of that file and if it didn't change in last minute than restart the script.

here is my python script:

## test.py

```
 import time
 import sys

 for i in range(100):
     time.sleep(1)
     sys.stdout.write('a'*i)
     sys.stdout.flush()
```

## wrapper_test

```
 #! /bin/bash

 PIDFILE=/home/jhon/workspace/producer/wrapper_test.pid

 case $1 in
   start)
     echo $$ > ${PIDFILE};
     exec /usr/bin/python /home/jhon/workspace/producer/test.py >> fetch_output.txt 2>&1
     ;;
   stop)
     kill `cat ${PIDFILE}`
     ;;
   *)
     echo "Usage: wrapper {start|stop}" 
     ;;

 esac
 exit 0
```

## /etc/monit/conf.d/test

```
 check process wrapper_test with pidfile /home/jhon/workspace/producer/wrapper_test.pid
   start program = "/home/jhon/workspace/producer/wrapper_test start"
   stop program = "/home/jhon/workspace/producer/wrapper_test stop"
   depends on fetch_output

 check file fetch_output with path /home/jhon/workspace/producer
   if timestamp > 1 minutes then
       exec "/usr/bin/monit restart wrapper_test"
```

The problem is that this script does not writes output to the file.
However I can do

```
ps aux | grep test
root     18333  0.0  0.0  31108  4612 ?        S    14:39   0:00 /usr/bin/python /home/jhon/workspace/producer/test.py
```

SO I can see it's working, but another thing that confuses me is when I do `monit status` fetch_output status parameter is `Invalid Type`, don't know what does it mean, but something definitely wrong.

```
Process 'wrapper_test'
  status                            Initializing
  monitoring status                 Initializing
  data collected                    Fri, 23 Aug 2013 14:32:17

File 'fetch_output'
  status                            Invalid type
  monitoring status                 Monitored
  permission                        0
  uid                               0
  gid                               0
  timestamp                         Wed, 31 Dec 1969 19:00:00
  size                              0 B
  data collected                    Fri, 23 Aug 2013 14:42:14
```

Comment: Could the working directory be something you're not expecting so fetch_output.txt ends up somewhere else?

Comment: Yay necrobump for me by the way haha